# What is the union of subobjects in a 2-category?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

I'm trying to understand how to take unions and intersections of subobjects in a 2-category (actually, I'm not 100% sure what subobjects are, but in the case I'm thinking about I have an idea). I understand that the intersection of subobjects in a category is given by their fiber product, if it exists, and then the union is computable via the corresponding pushout. However this doesn't seem to be the case in a higher category. Does anyone have any idea?

Edit: Assuming I'm working in the category of categories, I think the union of two subcategories $A,B\subset C$ should basically be the subcategory generated by $A,B$ and isomorphisms in $C$ between the objects of $A$ and $B$ — but I can't find a reference.

Comment: I think $2$-fibrations can handle a description of this situation, and generally speaking the definitions offered by fibrations tend to be the 'nice ones'. Are you familiar with $2$-fibrations, and if so have you attempted a similar construction to the [fibrational construction of subobjects in a $1$-category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/codomain+fibration#the_subobject_fibration)?

Comment: I am familiar with a notion of fibrations in a 2-category, but I haven't attempted a similar construction to the one in the link (it seems one should already know what a subobject is for this). You can assume I'm working in the category of categories. I think the union of two subcategories should basically be the subcategory generated by the two subcategories and isomorphisms between the objects of the two categories, but I can't find a reference.

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve. Indeed, in the first place, what even is a subobject in a 2-category? But once you decide that, and if you have chosen a reasonable definition, you will have a preordered set of subobjects for every object, and the union will be the least upper bound (when it exists).

Comment: Non-full subcategories don't behave very much like "subobjects" in 1-category theory.  If you use full subcategories, then they do.

Comment: @ZhenLin I agree my question is a bit vague, I'm basically asking if such a thing already exists in the literature.

Comment: What do you mean by "such a thing"? What properties do you want it to satisfy, what constructions should be examples, etc? Given two full subcategories A and B their union is the full subcategory spanned by the union of the sets of objects – this of course includes all the isomorphisms between them. If you restrict to full-on-iso subcategories (i.e. pseudomonic subobjects) that remains true. If you allow arbitrary non-full subcategories then you don't get that property.